# How to pass map value as a request parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

Any one can help. How I can pass below value as a request parameter. here data is key remaining values as parameters and how I can read these request value in my controller class. I am using spring with RestClient webservices.

```
"data" : [ { "key" : "Hi", "value": "true" } ]
```

Comment: Try to PUT it with additional braces like: ```{"data" : [ { "key" : "Hi", "value": "true" } ]}``` and header ```Content-Type: application/json```. In controller method arguments add @RequestBody Map map.

Comment: I s it possible to send as get method with this value as request parameter to the controller class...?

Comment: how I can pass "data" value as a request(ex: url?name='java') same like i need to pass(url?data="how I can pass kay ,value like map ")...Can any one help..

Comment: You can get query parameters by controller method argument like ```@RequestParam(value="name") String name```.

Comment: A workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581329/map-parameter-as-get-param-in-spring-rest-controller

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can pass it in the POST body as JSON and marshall it as required.
Request Parameters must be appended to the URL in the usual format

Answer (score 0):

Post Request ex:

```
"key":{
          "fullName":"FirstName LastName",
          "number":"1234",
          "age":"21"
    },
```

in model class we have to declare like:

```
 private Map<String, Object> key;
```